# How to manipulate CString's content

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, cstring

guys, I have a problem, please help me!
I have a CString variable which will receieve from Database,and the data may like this:(8)(9)(10)(11) or more.

Now I want to change every number in CString,for example, add 1,the outcome should like this:

CString Data; the contest of CString data variable should be changed.

Before: (8)(9)(10)(11)

After:  (9)(10)(11)(12)

I've tried Data.GetAt(i),but it returns a const pointer and I can't change it.

I konw maybe Data.GetBuffer() can get a pointer to manipulate CString,but I don't know how to do it.

So please help me ! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't change in-place.  Specifically in your example, when you change `(9)` to `(10)` it needs 1 extra character of buffer space.  Extract all the values somehow (a `std::list` of `int` perhaps), add whatever numbers you need, and then re-assemble into a string, and write it back all at once.

Comment: thank you very much, this method works. It seems like sometimes I should change the way I think. :)

Comment: Rayborn1105, now please mark the question as answered.  You're obviously new to the site (welcome), so hit the "checkbox" next to my answer if it's the one that solved (or got you on the right track) to your answer.  You can also up-vote answers that you like if you're viewing questions you're not the one who originally asked, or even up-vote multiple "good" answers to your own questions.